# How to show $f^{-1}(Y \backslash F) = X\backslash f^{-1}(F)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $E \subset X$ and $F \subset Y$, prove that $f^{-1}(Y \backslash F) =  X \backslash f^{-1}(F)$?

I'm assuming we just have to think of $f^{-1} (Y)$. I know the definition should be $f^{-1} (Y) = \{x \in X \ : \ f(X) \in Y\}$. But I don't see how we could end up with $f^{-1}(F)$ because that would imply $f^{-1}(F)= \{f(x): x\in X : f(x) \in F\}$ ?

Comment: Where is $E$ used?

Comment: This was a question with multiple subquestion, with proving  $f^{-1}(Y \backslash F) =  X \backslash f^{-1}(F)$ being one of them. I'm providing $E \subset X$ for completeness. I'm not really sure if I should\how to use E.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in f^{-1}(Y \setminus F)$. Then $f(x) \in Y$ and  $f(x) \not\in F$. Clearly, $x \in X$ and  we need $x \not\in f^{-1}(F)$. The latter follows directly from $f(x) \not \in F$. Thus $x \in X \setminus f^{-1}(F)$.

Let $x \in X \setminus f^{-1}(F)$. Then $x \in X$ and $x \not\in f^{-1}(F)$. Clearly, $f(x) \in Y$ and we need $f(x) \not\in F$. This follows directly from $x \not\in f^{-1}(F)$. Thus $f(x) \in Y \setminus F$ and therefore $x \in f^{-1}(Y \setminus F)$.

---

This whole argument basically is just an exercise in the definition of pre-image.

Answer (score 1):

The following statements are equivalent:

$x \in f^{-1}(Y \setminus F)$

$f(x) \in Y \setminus F$

$f(x) \notin F$

$x \notin f^{-1}(F)$

$x \in X \setminus f^{-1}(F)$

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how were you able to bring over the pre-image in line 2?

Comment: @Nikitau Write out the meaning of the first line in words. $x$ being in the preimage of $Y \setminus F$ literally means $f(x) \in Y \setminus F$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, by the definition, we have $$f^{-1}(Y \setminus F) = \{x\in X: f(x) \in Y\setminus F\}$$

and $$f^{-1}(F) = \{x\in X: f(x) \in F\}.$$

Then, if $x \in f^{-1}(X\setminus F)$, then $x \not\in f^{-1}(F)$, or $x \in X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$. So, $f^{-1}(X\setminus F) \subset X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$.

If $x \in X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$, then $f(x) \not\in F$, or $x \in f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)$.

So, you have the conclusion.

Comment: Wow. I did not think of directly using the definition. Thank you so much!